# Ethernet connection at work shows me a captive portal on Ubuntu, not on WIndows

Tags: windows, ethernet, captive-portal

I use my personal computer at work, I just plug it using a RJ45 and firefox automatically redirects me towards a captive portal, where I type in my institution credentials and I can access the web. I use Ubuntu.

One of my colleague has a windows laptop (property of the institution) that usually connects using Wi-Fi. We tried to connect it using ethernet in order to access printers. My colleague has his own credentials (that work on the Wi Fi captive portal). It just does not work using ethernet: it acts as if I was not connected at all, we cannot even access the captive portal page.

Any idea on how to make it work ? I can get info about the connection (because it works on my ubuntu pc)...

IT service is a mess, they tend to take computer and reset them, so we are trying to figure it on our own.

Edit (David's comment):

Ipconfig from windows pc (in French, sorry):

```
Carte Ethernet Connexion au réseau local :

Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::844f:5907:7552:c1f%10
Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.137.
Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :
```

Ifconfig from ubuntu pc successfully connected :

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.195.104  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.31.255.255
        inet6 fe80::a69e:fb0d:2790:a94f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:9e:f3:7a:f4:17  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 132465  bytes 82002810 (82.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 57868  bytes 7999429 (7.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7100000-f7120000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 14066  bytes 1383740 (1.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14066  bytes 1383740 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Edit2 (grawity's comment):

C:\Users\Mahdi>ipconfig /all

```
Configuration IP de Windows

   Nom de l'hôte . . . . . . . . . . : Wi-HP
   Suffixe DNS principal . . . . . . :
   Type de noeud. . . . . . . . . .  : Hybride
   Routage IP activé . . . . . . . . : Non
   Proxy WINS activé . . . . . . . . : Non

Carte réseau sans fil Connexion réseau sans fil :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205

   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : A0-88-B4-BA-CA-C8
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Oui
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui

Carte Ethernet Connexion au réseau local :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Con
nection
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 10-1F-74-C1-20-A7
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::844f:5907:7552:c1f%10(préféré)

   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.137.1(préféré)
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :
   IAID DHCPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . : 237774807
   DUID de client DHCPv6. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-A8-53-04-10-1F-74-C1-20
-A7
   Serveurs DNS. . .  . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS sur Tcpip. . . . . . . . . . . : Activé

Carte Tunnel isatap.{5250A0DA-1520-4575-BE9C-C382A896E459} :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Carte Microsoft ISATAP #2
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui

Carte Tunnel isatap.{EB8A8081-3958-4F9A-9BC8-0942FFEC74F2} :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Carte Microsoft ISATAP #3
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui

Carte Tunnel isatap.{EC57BAE2-C7AE-4947-BA24-73455A2F55BE} :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Carte Microsoft ISATAP
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui

Carte Tunnel Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Adresse physique . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP activé. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Non
   Configuration automatique activée. . . : Oui
```

C:\Users\Mahdi>netsh interface ipv4 show address

```
Configuration pour l'interface « Connexion réseau sans fil »
    DHCP activé:                          Oui
    Adresse IP :                           172.20.10.13
    Préfixe de sous-réseau :               172.20.10.0/28 (masque 255.255.255.24
0)
    Passerelle par défaut :               172.20.10.1
    Métrique de passerelle :              0
    Métrique de l'interface :             25

Configuration pour l'interface « Connexion au réseau local »
    DHCP activé :                         Non
    Adresse IP :                           192.168.137.1
    Préfixe de sous-réseau :               192.168.137.0/24 (masque 255.255.255.
0)
    Métrique de l'interface :             20

Configuration pour l'interface « Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 »
    DHCP activé :                         Non
    Adresse IP :                           127.0.0.1
    Préfixe de sous-réseau :               127.0.0.0/8 (masque 255.0.0.0)
    Métrique de l'interface :             50
```

Edit3: Making it clearer following @Christopher Hostage suggestion.

Comment: What does ipconfig tell you?

Comment: Thanks Robert for the suggestion. I desactivated it but it does not have any effect unfortunately.

Comment: Can you post the `ipconfig /all` information, or `netsh interface ipv4 show address`? (Please don't edit out anything.)

Comment: @Robert, Oooh I see... Thanks I'll look into that. Maybe there is a way to request a connection without passing 802.11X, even from a Windows computer ?

Comment: @lhoppe I converted my comments to an answer.

Comment: Another possibility is that the network has MAC address filtering, and that the new computer was never added to the Allowed List.  This is a common security method at companies, to make it harder for unauthorized computers to connect to the network.  Like, some friend's PC that he brought in.  If this is a PC brought in from the outside, ask IT to add it to the Allowed List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a network works in Windows but not in Linux on the same computer there are multiple possibilities:

1. The network configuration is (partly) statically and have to be set manually in Linux the same way as in Windows (IP address, subnet mask, gateway, DNS)
2. There may be system-wide proxy configuration on Windows which is not applied automatically on Linux.
3. Your network may be configured to use 802.11X authentication: You this in the Windows network configuration (properties of Ethernet adapter) if it uses 802.11X computer authentication.

Note: 802.11X is a network security configuration of your used network port. I assume it is applied to prevent network access to unauthorized computers.
Using 802.11X Windows can be configured to authenticate itself using certificates(+private key) to the network switch. Only if the system passes this authentication you are allowed to access the network.
Linux doe snot have access to those certificates and therefore fails the authentication and is getting redirected to the captive portal..

You can't change this behavior on your computer, this can only be changed by a network administrator who has access to the switch your computer is connected to.